# Android - findViewById is partially working

Tags: android-layout, android-asynctask, findviewbyid, setcontentview

I have an xml with two siblings view as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="45"
    android:layout_rowWeight="10"
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:text="First\nLow" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="12:16 AM"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_columnWeight="45"
    android:layout_rowWeight="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/time" />
```

And here is my code:

```
TextView type_textView = (TextView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.type);
TextView time_textView = (TextView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.time);
```

The object `time_textView` is working fine. The problem is that `type_textView` is `null`!

Both TextViews are in the same layout and they both have the same parent layout (siblings).
This is actually happening with 10 other TextViews while 20 other siblings TextViews are working fine.
I brought only two siblings to make the question straight forward.

I searched and tried all related findViewById solutions:

```
 1. Clean and Rebuild.
 2. Delete XML and and add it again.
 3. Cache Invalidate and Restart.
 4. SetContentView().
 5. Fixing all errors in all XML files (I still have tons of silly warnings like must use @dimens and @strings).
 6. Make the ID's unique among all XML files.
```

If it matters, I'm doing all of that inside AsyncTask `doInBackground`. I tried and moved it to `onPostExecute` and still the same problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other views in the layout that you're calling `findViewById` on with the id `type`?

Comment: Are you calling `findViewById()` from your Async's `doInBackground()`?

Comment: @Matthew Nope. 
[at]John P. Yes, I'm and I tried to do it in onPostExecute, too.